# WebContentTypeMapper doesn't exist in System.ServiceModel.Channels?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Wondering if anyone has had this issue before - from everything I'm reading 'WebContentTypeMapper' should live in  'System.ServiceModel.Channels' however it doesn't appear there when I try to access it.

Have I not got something installed in my environment that I should? I can't seem to find any good info on this.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Always helpful to specify the .Net framework version. If you are just missing dll then it could be in system.servicemodel.web.dll

Comment: I am not certain, but I suspect it may have moved because the stuff I was reading seemed to have it elsewhere.. Thanks. (it was .net 4.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.webcontenttypemapper.aspx) that type is in `System.ServiceModel.Web.dll`